# How to cast to a List<IEnumerable<XElement>>

Tags: c#, list, casting, ienumerable, xelement

I was doing this first to return a particular set of nodes under the parent node that had id equal to 1 which worked fantastically.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> world1 = LevelData.root.
                               Elements("world").
                               Where(element => (int?)element.Attribute("id") == 1);
```

But i needed to do this multiple times and each to have there own instance so i thought to put them into a list but  it doesn't even compile telling me error CS0266:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
List<IEnumerable<XElement>>[] World = new List<IEnumerable<XElement>>[noofworlds];

        foreach (List<IEnumerable<XElement>> wn in World)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("World: "+w);

            //this will make a list of all the nodes (elements) within the world specified by the id tag
            World[w] =  LevelData.Root.Elements("world").Where(element => (int?)element.Attribute("id") == 1);//with id == to i
            w++;
        }
```

So I tried adding the cast `List<IEnumerable<XElement>>` just before `LevelData.root.` 
but then i get a invalidcastexception. I'm at a brick wall on where to go. Any advice?

Comment: Your `World` variable is an array of lists of `IEnumerable`s of `XElement`.  I'm pretty sure you never want to do that.

Comment: Why do you never want to do that? whats the drawbacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Where` method doesn't return a `List<>`, it returns an `IEnumerable<>`, which is lazy-evaluated when it is enumerated.

If you want an actual `List<>` object, stick a `.ToList()` at the end, and that will do it.

Answer (score 4):

```
var world1 = LevelData.root
                           .Elements("world")
                           .Where(element => (int?)element.Attribute("id") == 1)
                           .ToList();
```

You need to use [ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) to convert it from [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), because the [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) interface supports more functionality than the [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert an `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>` by calling `ToList()`

```
List<XElement> world1 = LevelData.root
    .Elements("world")
    .Where(element => (int?)element.Attribute("id") == 1)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit confusing, you seem to have an array of `List<IEnumerable<XElement>>` and you are trying to assign a `IEnumerable<XElement>` to it.

If you just want a `List` of `IEnumerable<XElement>` this should work

```
List<IEnumerable<XElement>> World = new List<IEnumerable<XElement>>();
for (int i = 0; i < noofworlds; i++)
{
    World.Add(LevelData.Root.Elements("world").Where(element => (int?)element.Attribute("id") == i));//with id == to i
}
```

Otherwise tou are going to have to create a new list to add to the array and add the `IEnumerable<XElement>` to that list.

```
List<IEnumerable<XElement>>[] World = new List<IEnumerable<XElement>>[noofworlds];
for (int i = 0; i < noofworlds; i++)
{
    World[i] = new List<IEnumerable<XElement>> { (LevelData.Root.Elements("world").Where(element => (int?)element.Attribute("id") == i)) };//with id == to i
}
```